# PHP - file_get_contents() with variable in string?

Tags: php, file-get-contents, phpmailer

Im trying to email an order with PHPMailer to the customer when this order is received.
I tried doing that this way:

```
        $email_page = file_get_contents("email_order_html.php?order=$order_id");
```

I want to get the contents of this page as string so I can send this with PHPMailer but this function wont execute the page because of the variable $order_id in it, how can I fix this?

Comment: file_get_contents does support URIs - http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: @holodoc true, but i'd say the issue is likely that the OP doesnt know the difference between calling it with a URI and a local file.

Comment: In fact I think he does :) He is simply using a dynamic page to generate the required content based on the order_id which is sent with the request. Perhaps a bit odd way to do it but certainly not the worst I've seen :)

Comment: @holodoc just that file_get_content wont generate a page here because its fetching the file from the filesystem and that wont execute it all. There is no request.

Comment: Hm... Valid point... Argument doesn't start with a protocol identifier :(

Answer (score 5):

You can only add Query Params when using `file_get_contents` with an Url Aware Stream Wrapper, e.g. it would work for `http://localhost/yourfile.php?foo=bar`. Doing so would issue an HTTP Get Request to a webserver at localhost with the specified query params. The request would be processed and the result of the request would be returned.

When using `file_get_contents` with a filename only, there wont be any HTTP Requests. The call will go directly to your file system. Your file system is not a webserver. PHP will only read the file contents. It wont execute the PHP script and will only return the text in it.

You should [`include`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) the file and call whatever the script does manually. If the script depends on the order argument, set it via `$_GET['order'] = $orderId` before including the file.

Answer (score 4):

One of the certainly better ways to do it would be to use output buffering combined with simply including the content creating script.

```
// $order_id is certainly available in place where file_get_contents has been used...
ob_start();
require 'email_order_html.php';
$email_page = ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 4):

email_template.php

```
<body>
<p>{foo}</p>
<p>{bar}</p>
</body>
```

sendmail.php

```
../

$mail = new PHPMailer(); 

//get the file:
$body = file_get_contents('email_template.php');
$body = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

//setup vars to replace
$vars = array('{foo}','{bar}');
$values = array($foor,$bar);

//replace vars
$body = str_replace($vars,$values,$body);

//add the html tot the body
$mail->MsgHTML($body);

/...
```

Hope it helps someone ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
use require("email_order_html.php");
```

and `$order_id` will available in your file

Comment: yes and no. It will be available but depending on how the script looks like, it wont help the OP. Given that he's trying to pass it as a URI param, the script likely requires it to be in $_GET.

Comment: But $order_id is surely available in place where he used to call file_get_contents.

Answer (score 1):

As Gordon said, `file_get_contents()` reads files from the filesystem - text or binary files, that is, not the result of the execution of those files.

You can use Curl ([docs](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2007/06/php_tip_how_get_web_page_using_curl)) to do that, in case you'll want to move the script to a separate server. At the moment, simply including the file and passing the arguments directly to the function you want is a more sensitive approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
$email_page = file_get_contents("email_order_html.php?order=".$order_id);
```

file_get_contents can read content in url too, at least, in 2021, yes it can.